# Setting blob MIME type to wav still results in webM

Tags: javascript, blob

I followed [this article](https://medium.com/@bryanjenningz/how-to-record-and-play-audio-in-javascript-faa1b2b3e49b) (the code up to step 6) to make an audio recorder as below. After making the `audioBlob`, I call a custom function to upload the blob. This function works for other file types.

I pass `{ type: 'audio/wav' }` to the `Blob` constructor. The resulting file indeed pretends to be a wave file, and would play fine in the browser, but not on iOS. I checked with http://checkfiletype.com/ and discovered the file was actually WebM:

[image]

How do I ensure the file is in fact a `.wav` file?

The code as edited from that article:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start();

    const audioChunks = [];
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
      const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });

      // Custom upload function
      uploadFile(audioBlob);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
    }, 3000);
  });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How do I ensure the file is in fact a .wav file?

Quite easy, no browsers (I know of) does support exporting to *wav* natively. So you can be sure your file is not a wav file.

The `type` option of the Blob constructor only says the browser how it should set the MIME-type for further needs (e.g when it will send it to a server). 
But it doesn't actually change the content you passed as the first argument.

So it won't magically transform your webm file to an other format.

Now, you do have [some options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder#Syntax) to change the format to which the MediaRecorder will output its content, but the set of supported formats / codecs is up to the implementations, and I don't think any browser supports anything else than *opus*, either in a *webm* container or in an *ogg* * one (* FF only).

***[edit]: Actually Chrome now [supports PCM in webm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729039/pcm-support-in-webm-and-chromes-webm-implementation).***

Thanks to the [*isTypeSupported*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/isTypeSupported) method, you can very well setup your code to use this format if it ever becomes available, but I personally wouldn't grow too much hope on this, and would [look somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560413/html5-web-audio-convert-audio-buffer-into-wav-file) if it is required to output a *wav* file...

```
const mime = ['audio/wav', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/webm', 'audio/ogg']
  .filter(MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported)[0];
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
  mimeType: mime
});
```

Comment: any other way to convert audio/webm or audio/ogg content to audio/wav format ?