# Recording audio from mic to .wav file using Web Audio API and ScriptProcessorNode

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, audio-recording

I want to record audio from mic into [`.wav`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) format using [Web Audio api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) and [`ScriptProcessorNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode).

I tried to create such recording with the help of

- [Use JavaScript to record audio as .wav in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58785295/use-javascript-to-record-audio-as-wav-in-chrome)
- https://web.dev/media-recording-audio/
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/capturing-voice-input-in-a-browser/

Here is my code

```js
let button = document.createElement('button')
button.innerHTML = 'Start'
button.addEventListener('click', startRecording)
document.body.appendChild(button)

let listening = false;
let numChannels = 1;
let recBuffers = [[], []];
let recLength = 0;
let maxTime = 5000;
let context

function startRecording() {
  const handleSuccess = function (stream) {
    let audioContext = new AudioContext({
      // latencyHint: 'interactive',
      sampleRate: 44100,
    });
    const source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    context = source.context;
    const node = (context.createScriptProcessor || context.createJavaScriptNode).call(context, 4096, numChannels, numChannels);

    source.connect(node);
    node.connect(audioContext.destination);

    node.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
      if (!listening) return;

      for (var i = 0; i < numChannels; i++) {
        recBuffers[i].push([...e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(i)]);
      }

      recLength += recBuffers[0][0].length;
    };
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
    .then(handleSuccess);

}

function beginRecording() {
  recBuffers = [[], []];
  recLength = 0;
  listening = true;
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    endRecording();
  }, maxTime);
}

function endRecording() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = null;
  let alok = exportWAV();
  console.log('alok', alok)
  let link = document.createElement('a')
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(alok)
  link.download = 'alok.wav'
  link.click()
}

function mergeBuffers(buffers, len) {
  let result = new Float32Array(len);
  let offset = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < buffers.length; i++) {
    result.set(buffers[i], offset);
    offset += buffers[i].length;
  }
  return result;
}

function interleave(inputL, inputR) {
  let len = inputL.length + inputR.length;
  let result = new Float32Array(len);

  let index = 0;
  let inputIndex = 0;

  while (index < len) {
    result[index++] = inputL[inputIndex];
    result[index++] = inputR[inputIndex];
    inputIndex++;
  }

  return result;
}

function exportWAV() {
  let buffers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numChannels; i++) {
    buffers.push(mergeBuffers(recBuffers[i], recLength));
  }

  let interleaved = numChannels == 2 ? interleave(buffers[0], buffers[1]) : buffers[0];
  let dataView = encodeWAV(interleaved);
  let blob = new Blob([dataView], { type: 'audio/wav' });
  blob.name = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) + '.wav';

  listening = false;

  return blob;
}

function floatTo16BitPCM(output, offset, input) {
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset += 2) {
    var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
    output.setInt16(offset, s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF, true);
  }
}

function writeString(view, offset, string) {
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
  }
}

function encodeWAV(samples) {
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
  var view = new DataView(buffer);

  /* RIFF identifier */
  writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
  /* file length */
  view.setUint32(4, 36 + samples.length * 2, true);
  /* RIFF type */
  writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
  /* format chunk identifier */
  writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
  /* format chunk length */
  view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
  /* sample format (raw) */
  view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
  /* channel count */
  view.setUint16(22, numChannels, true);
  /* sample rate */
  view.setUint32(24, 44100 || context.sampleRate, true);
  /* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
  view.setUint32(28, 44100 || context.sampleRate * 4, true);
  /* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
  view.setUint16(32, numChannels * 2, true);
  /* bits per sample */
  view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
  /* data chunk identifier */
  writeString(view, 36, 'data');
  /* data chunk length */
  view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true);

  floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);

  return view;
}

beginRecording()
```

This code is working fine but generated audio is not playing. What correction is needed in this code to make correct wav data?

Comment: Any specific reason you want create wav file using the WebAudioAPI and ScriptProcessorNode? I tried using method from the [post](https://air.ghost.io/recording-to-an-audio-file-using-html5-and-js) and It worked for me

Comment: @HitenRastogi: I want to pass .wav file as input to https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/